# Problem while installing Wine with packages

Tags: package-management, system-installation, wine, dependencies

I followed the instructions to install the latest stable wine version but at the last step I get this :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 winehq-stable : Dépend: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~bionic-1)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».

The following packages contain unfulfilled dependencies: 
winehq-stable: Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0 ~ bionic-1) 
E: Unable to fix problems, bad packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The following packages contain unfulfilled dependencies: winehq-stable: Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0 ~ bionic-1) E: Unable to fix problems, bad packages are in "keep as is" mode.

Comment: Please edit your question: Add a link to "the instructions."  Also add the complete output of `sudo apt update`.